# java: runtime equivalent of casting between numeric types

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types

I can do this when I know the object types at compile-time:

```
int obj1 = 3;
float obj2 = (float)obj1;
int obj3 = (int)obj1;
short obj4 = (short)obj1;
```

What's the most efficient simple way to produce the same conversion between numeric types, with object types known at runtime?

```
// given a primitive (or boxed primitive) number class,
// returns a number that's a boxed instance of that class, 
// equivalent in value to the appropriate primitive cast
// (otherwise throws an IllegalArgumentException)
public Number runtimeNumericCast(Number sourceNumber, 
         Class<?> resultType)
{
   ...
}

Number obj1 = 3;  // really an Integer
Number obj2 = runtimeNumericCast(obj1, Float.class); // will return 3.0f
Number obj3 = runtimeNumericCast(obj2, int.class) // will return 3
Number obj4 = runtimeNumericCast(obj3, Short.class) // will return (short)3
```

The best I can think of is to use a `Map<Class<?>, Function<Number,Number>>` and declare one function for each of the 6 numeric primitive types to return `Number.byteValue()`, `Number.shortValue()`, `Number.intValue()`, `Number.longValue()`, `Number.floatValue()`, and `Number.doubleValue()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I would have done it, except for the method signature to avoid unnecessary casting:

```
public <T extends Number> T runtimeNumericCast(Number sourceNumber, 
         Class<T> resultType)
```

Comment: +1, good idea (although doesn't work for `int.class` vs. `Integer.class` since `int.class` is different)